# How to show text on camera app without to record it #Android #Camera API

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, kotlin-android-extensions

I want to show a text when the camera app is opened. Something like 'Hello World!' but must not be recorded, just viewable like an overlay on the app, while I am recording a video.

Comment: Write your own camera code, using CameraX, Fotoapparat, CameraKit/Android, or another library. Put a `TextView` on top of the view that renders the camera preview.

Comment: @CommonsWare So, from what I understand, I can add a TextView while recording, by using CameraKit/Android library.  Thanx for the answer!